# ugly HTML in HTML Helper in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I construct HTML in an HtmlHelper method, it looks really ugly because I have to either backslash or double my double quotes, like this:

```
var html = @"<input type=""text"" name =""firstName"">";
```

It's even worse if I want to use `string.Format` together with Angular-JS because then I have to output quadruple curly braces:

```
var html = string.Format(@"{0} Rate: {{{{model.Rate}}}}", rateType);
```

And of course there is no HTML syntax highlighting in this environment.  Is there any way to write somewhat normal-looking HTML inside a helper?

Comment: Are you talking about how it looks once rendered, or in the IDE?

Comment: Why are you creating your html like that? Why not actually use the helper method? @Html.TextBox("firstName") ? Or are you actually writing your own helper method to generate a text box?

Comment: In the IDE... it looks fine once rendered

Comment: I'm writing a helper to generate a whole section of HTML... the text box was only an example

Answer (score 2):

What about using `'` instead of `"`

```
var html = @"<input type='text' name ='firstName'>";
```

Comment: LOL. that is an awesome answer.